# Read two QR codes at the same time using Zxing

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code

I'm working on an app that has to read two QR codes.
Any idea about doing this with Zxing?

Also, I need to save the value (consider x and y coordinates) of these QR codes, is it possible?

Comment: Are you limited to zxing or other libraries can be used?

Comment: zxing... have u tried other?

Comment: Yes, http://pdf417.mobi supports reading more than one barcode at once. It's commercial SDK. Disclaimer: I'm part of the team that developed it.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't have to use ZXing.**

### 2016 update

The current recommendation is to use the [Android Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview), which works [locally](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html) (offline), [without](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes) requiring a server roundtrip:

> The Barcode API detects barcodes in real-time, on device, in any orientation. **It can also detect multiple barcodes at once.**
>
> It reads the following barcode formats:
>
> - 1D barcodes: EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar
> - 2D barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC
>
> It automatically parses QR Codes, Data Matrix, PDF-417, and Aztec values [...]

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to scan barcodes is to use the zxing [IntentIntegrator](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).
There are different options for saving data on Android. Check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) are probably the easiest way to store some data.

Answer (score -1):

You can go and check the zxing page (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). You might find useful information about how to use it.

There are multiple ways to use it in your application :

1. Use it as an external library, assuming the user has already downloaded it or will download it, then access it via `intent`([check here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android)).
2. Just copy paste the lib in your project and modify stuffs in order to make it work without using `intent`.
3. Copy it and still use it as intents.

For the second part of your question, you might need to take a closer look into the ZXING sources, you might be able to find traces of stuffs like coordinates.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i need to read the two qrcode in the same time! Do u think it s possible to do?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.